# Shortcode with custom content attribute?

Tags: functions, shortcode

I am creating a shortcode for a client site that should display an image and a saying (mainly at the bottom of the page, but basically wherever the client wants to insert said image/saying).  The image would remain the same, and there will be a "standard saying", but the client would like the potential to change the saying on a per-page basis.

I have the following working code which works great when using the **[call_to_action]** shortcode:

```
<?php 
function shortcode_call_to_action() { 
$stylesheetdir = get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');
return '<div id="call_to_action"> <img src="' . $stylesheetdir . '/images/call_to_action.jpg" /> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, jus ludus dignissim delenit incassum adipiscing, letalis ymo loquor populus sed saepius. Quod regula vulputate eum nulla, feugait foras ex ideo. </p>' ;
}
add_shortcode('call_to_action', 'shortcode_call_to_action');    
?>
```

What I'd like to do, somehow, is add an attribute in there, somewhere, so that the client can change/overwrite the call_to_action text by changing it right in the shortcode:

**[call_to_action]This would be the new overwritten text that would show up if inserted here.[/call_to_action]**

I would also like it to respect any html (paragraph and/or break) tags that might be used.  Willing to re-write my previous function if necessary.  I'm a php noob so I can't seem to figure this one out.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks SE!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second parameter of your shortcode function is the content. So rewrite the function:

```
function shortcode_call_to_action( $attributes = NULL, $content = '' ) 
{ 
    $stylesheetdir = get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');

    if ( '' === $content )
    {   // use a default text if there is no content
        $content = 'default text';
    }

    return "<div id='call_to_action'> <img src='$stylesheetdir/images/call_to_action.jpg' alt='' /> 
        <p>$content</p>";
}
```

If the user writes …

```
[call_to_action]Custom text[/call_to_action]
```

… the parameter `$content` in your function will be set to that text.

For more details see the [Shortcode API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API).