# Shortcode for pulling specific Post Title outside loop when ID is passed in

Tags: loop, shortcode

I want to be able to create a shortcode that will return the post title when I pass in the ID of the post. I.E. [myshortcode_title ID=1234]

I have a shortcode that pulls the post title from the current post:

```
function myshortcode_title( ){
   return get_the_title();
}
add_shortcode( 'page_title', 'myshortcode_title' );
```

I've seen shortcodes that can pass in attributes and return a result outside the loop, but I'm still new at WP shortcodes.

Comment: See related: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/58438/shortcode-with-custom-content-attribute

Answer (score 0):

Codex documentation for shortcodes has a section on [Handling Attributes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Handling_Attributes).

In a nutshell attributes will get passed on to your callback and you need to implement handling them with your code within it:

```
function my_shortcode_handler( $atts, $content = null ) {
    $a = shortcode_atts( array(
        'attr_1' => 'attribute 1 default',
        'attr_2' => 'attribute 2 default',
        // ...etc
    ), $atts );
}
```

Comment: I didn't know I'd have to extract and store the ID into an array to do this. I was hoping it was a simple lookup I could use.

Comment: The extraction will be performed by WP for you. This _is_ relatively easy in practice once you figure basics of it. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used to get the result I want which is post title by passing in post ID:

```
// Get Post Title outside of loop
// USE: [get-post-details post="123"]

function title_by_id($atts) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'post' => 0,
    ), $atts, 'title-from-id' );   
    $id = $atts['post'];               
    $data = get_the_title($id);        
    return $data;                      
}
add_shortcode( 'title-from-id', 'title_by_id' );
```